# Config SMTP of office365 for another connected email

Tags: office365, smtp, email-client

I have an account at office365 and connected another email to it. For example:

> test1@hotmail.com
>
> test1@gmail.com --> can log in to Hotmail via this email

Each of them works fine with their SMTP configuration. But I need to use office365 SMTP for the second email. In the example, it is gmail domain but in real world it is the customer's domain.

So I will have a configuration like this:

```
Server host: smtp.office365.com
Port: 587 (With TLS)
Username: test1@gmail.com
Password: App password of Gmail
```

But it doesn't work. It shows an error about the credential problem:

> Invalid login: 535 5.7.139 Authentication unsuccessful, the user
> credentials were incorrect.

So at first, is this possible? If yes what is the problem here?

Thanks